# How to make IntelliJ to propose "Create class" instead of "Add Maven dependency .."

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to know How to make IntelliJ to propose "Create class" instead to have "Add Maven Dependency ..." when I write a new class name.

See the print screen.

[image: Showing Add Maven Dependency]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type also field/variable name.

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm !! I have searched this everywhere inside InteliJ. Thanks a lot !